# Resize background Image different desktop screen size

Tags: css, media-queries

Background image does not resize on different desktop screens with the following style. What's wrong here?

```
@media
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-device-width: 539px) {
    /* Large screen, retina */
    .welcome {
        background:#00ff00;
        /* link to other image */
        background-image: url('Desktop768px1024px.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        /* hide src */
        height:0;
        width:0;

        /* just show the background */
        padding:768px 1024px;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dppx` and `px` at same target, seems weird... :) Are you testing in what device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this rule:

```
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 72dpi) and (min-device-width: 539px) {}
```